# Bash Shell Scripting: How to Sum the Values in a File With the Use of For Loop and bc Command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm currently trying to write a function in my bash script that does the following: Take in a file as an argument and calculate the sum of the numbers within that file. I must make use of a for loop and the bc command.

Example of values in the file (each value on their own line):

```
12
4
53
19
6
```

So here's what I have so far:

```
function sum_values() {
  for line in $1; do
  #not sure how to sum the values using bc
  done
}
```

Am I on the right track? I'm not sure how to implement the bc command  in this situation.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for best practices re: processing a stream line-by-line. Also, note that whoever set your assignment was instructing you to use bad practices: [**`for` loops should not be used to iterate over line-oriented content.**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: ...well, not unless you read that line-oriented content into an array first; for example: `readarray -t values <file` would put your values into an array called `values`, which you could iterate over with something of the form of `for value in "${values[@]}"; do echo "processing $value"; done`.

Comment: ...and btw, using the `function` keyword is not particularly good form -- it makes your code incompatible with baseline POSIX implementations of `/bin/sh`, but -- unlike more useful bashisms -- adds no value in return for that incompatibility; POSIX function declaration is just `sum_values() {` with no preceding `function`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy heh :), Don't forget than most teachers teaching `bash` will not understands the half of good `bash` answers in this site... so...

Answer (score 2):

You are *not* on track. Why?

- You are passing the whole file content as a variable which requires to store the whole file in memory. Not a problem with a `1`, `2`, `3` example, big no go in real life.
- You are iterating over the content of a file using a `for in` loop assuming that you are iterating over the *lines* of that file. That is not true, because word splitting will be performed which makes the `for in` loop literally iterate over *words*, not *lines*.
- As others mentioned, the shell is not the right tool for it. That's because such kind of processing is very slow with the shell compared to `awk` for example. Furthermore the shell is not able to perform floating point operations, meaning you can only process integers. Use `awk`.

Correct would be (with bash, for educational purposes):

```
# Expects a filename
sum() {
    filename=${1}
    s=0
    while read -r line ; do
        # Arithmetic expansion
        s=$((s+line))
        # Or with bc
        # s=$(bc <<< "${s}+${line}")
        # With floating point support
        # s=$(bc -l <<< "${s}+${line}")
    done < "${filename}"
    echo "${s}"
}

sum filename
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '{s+=$0}END{print s}' filename
```

Comment: Maybe point out that in addition to brevity, the Awk solution is better because it can cope with floating point, too.

Comment: very good point! Also I forgot that the OP wanted to use `bc` for the calculation. Just woke up. Will change this later.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily without the need of a for loop.

```
paste -s -d+ numbers.txt | bc
```

Answer (score 0):

While `awk` (or other higher level language: `perl`, `python`, etc) would be better suited for this task, you are on the right track for doing it the naive way. Tip:

```
$ x=1
$ y=$(bc <<<"$x + 1")
$ echo $y
2
```

Answer (score 0):

To do math in bash we surround an operation in $(( ... ))

Here are some examples:

```
$(( 5 + 5 )) # 10

my_var = $((5 + 5)) # my_var is now 10

my_var = $(($my_var + 5)) # my_var is now 10
```

Solution to your problem:

```
function sum_values() {
    sum=0
    for i in $(<$1); do
        sum=$(($sum + $i))
    done
    echo $sum
}
```

Note that you could have also done $(cat $1) instead of $(<$1) in the solution above.

Edit: Replaced return $sum with echo $sum

Comment: Returning `$sum`? What about `sum=-1` or `sum=256` etc? That won't really work.

Comment: @PesaThe not exactly sure what you are saying, but i am returning the value of sum from the function

Comment: Value of return status is restricted to 0 - 255. If the sum is a number not in this range, your script will misbehave.

Comment: @PesaThe ahh, good catch! I had no idea.

Comment: so you can replace `return` with `echo` ;-). Good luck to all.